# Spotify - Track ID Features

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to acquire Spotify track ID's and I want to limit the number of non-functional ones that I have to trawl through. Are there any notable features of the track ID's that I can use to optimize my search? (Excluding that they are made from 0-9a-zA-Z chars, and that they are 22 chars long)

Answer (score 4):

The IDs are randomly generated UUID4, converted to a fixed 22 character wide zero left padded base62 representation to be slightly shorter than hex and avoiding the non-alphanumeric characters of base64.

The only way to validate is by looking them up with the Web API. You could look at the 4 in the UUID4 hex representation, but that still doesn't mean the ID points to any actual resource.